# R- Conversion to TS

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am currently struggling to convert a set of data into TS format.

```
Call_VolumeTS10 <- ts(Forecast_Data_Test$`Call Volume`, frequency = 578, start = c(2019, 1,1), end=c(2020, 7, 31))
```

However, the code does not properly convert data into a daily time series.

Is it a problem with my code?

Comment: I believe that `frequency` argument requires additional attention. Please check: https://otexts.com/fpp2/ts-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @AlexB, the value for frequency is certainly oddly defined. However, the error you're having it's also related to how you defined `start` and `end`.

You cannot define `start` and `end` with a numeric vector of length 3. It must be a vector of length 2: the first number should be the year (or, generically speaking, the number of seasons that have passed) and the second number should be a number between 1 and the value of the frequency.

To properly write your ts, you should use this code:

```
Call_VolumeTS10 <- ts(Forecast_Data_Test$`Call Volume`, frequency = 365.25, start = c(2019, 1))
```

Start, end and frequency will be defined as follow:

```
your_data <- rnorm(578)
your_ts <- ts(your_data, start = c(2019, 1), frequency = 365.25)
tsp(your_ts)
#> [1] 2019.00 2020.58  365.25
## respectively: start end frequency
```

---

However, I suppose you want to define a `ts` to forecast it.

The problem is that a frequency of 365.25 is rarely handled correctly by forecasting methods (for example `forecast::auto.arima` or `forecast::ets`).

Probably you may need to use `frequency = 7`. Of course, in that case, the value for `end` in the time series definition will make no sense.

```
your_data <- rnorm(578)
your_ts <- ts(your_data, start = c(2019, 1), frequency = 7)
tsp(your_ts)
#> [1] 2019.000 2101.429    7.000
## respectively: start end frequency
```

Obviously, it has no meaning. So it would just make more sense to define it this way:

```
your_data <- rnorm(578)
your_ts <- ts(your_data, frequency = 7)
tsp(your_ts)
#> [1]  1.00000 83.42857  7.00000
## respectively: start end frequency
```

In this case, you can interpret the difference between 1.000 and 83.428 as if 82 weeks has passed since the beginning of the time series (plus a couple of days).

---

Alternatively, you can use the `msts` function from the `forecast` package that allows you to define multiple frequencies.

```
library(forecast)
msts(your_ts, start = c(2019, 1), seasonal.periods = c(7, 365.25))
your_ts


#> Multi-Seasonal Time Series:
#> Start: 2019 1
#> Seasonal Periods: 7 365.25
#> Data:
#> ...
```

That `msts` object is well-integrated with `forecast::fourier` and `forecast::tbats`.

I suggest you to have a look at [this](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/) for some ideas about it.

---

About how to write `start` in a proper way...

"2019-01-01" is a pretty convenient day, because the right value for start will be `c(2019, 1)`. However, if you find yourself with the need to write a different start date, I suggest you to use this code to define the start time:

```
start = c(lubridate::year(date), as.numeric(format(date, "%j")))
```

Where `date` is any date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.